# I want to point subdomain from my hosting account1 to another server

Tags: hosting, subdomain

I have website website1.com and I would to create subdomain sub.website1.com and point that subdomain to another website website2.com . how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need redirection then just point the DNS entry to the other server. If you do, then create a new virtual host in your web server and add the redirection there.

Comment: website1.com run on linux hosting and use cpanel and website2.com run on windows hosting and use plesk control panel and I use in both shared hosting .

Comment: And none of that changes what I said.